# heroku and node.js is not finding a php file with the request module

Tags: node.js, express

Using Heroku, node.js, the npmjs request module, express and php, heroku log is reporting that it can not find a php file.

I am making a GET request from node.js in the index.js server that I made in the Heroku dyno web.1 with this url: "https://chatscroll-code2.herokuapp.com/login2.php" with the hope of receiving some json data back from the php file.

```
var requestOptions = {
    url : "https://chatscroll-code2.herokuapp.com/login2.php",
    json : {}
};

request(requestOptions , function(err, resp, body) { 
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } 
    else if (resp.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log(body);
    } else {
        console.log("returned status code="+resp.statusCode);
        callback(body);
    }
});
```

The error that I get back from Heroku says that it "Cannot GET /login2.php." The html presented error value from Heroku is contained in the returned body variable.

In the code, body should contain: "{\"result\":"."\"1\",\"reason\":"."\"Successful login\"}";
or
"{\"result\":"."\"0\",\"reason\":"."\"Unsuccessful login\"}";

Comment: You need to give us more info on what is happening to you when you execute your code.  Are you receiving some sort of error?

Answer (score 0):

welcome to StackOverflow !

I think the problem is that you should use the `POST` method to reach this PHP page. Check in the PHP code which method it is handling.

If it is handling the `POST` method, your code should look something like this:

```
var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://chatscroll-code2.herokuapp.com/login2.php',
  form: {
    username: 'something',
    password: 'greatpassword' // encrypt with something like PBKDF2
  }
}

request(requestOptions, function (err, resp, body) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  } else if (resp.statusCode === 200) {
    console.log(body)
  } else {
    console.log('returned status code=' + resp.statusCode)
    callback(body)
  }
})
```

I have a [Discord server](https://discord.gg/C2bVzgb) where we help each others, don't hesitate joining it :)

Comment: Thank you SherloxFR for your welcome message and answer. I have tried the POST method. That does not work either. I get the same error. Also, thank you for your invitation!

Comment: @John100 could you provide us with the PHP code & the Apache (or the PHP webserver you are using) logs please ?